# Adding dynamic fields on click of button in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to add a field dynamically when click on button in extjs 4.What I have done is added a onchange function on add button and write the adding textfield logic in that function.
Here is my code.

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.Edit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.useredit',
    requires: ['Ext.form.Panel'],
    title : 'Edit User',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,
    height: 300,
    width: 280,
    id : 'mainPanel',
        initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                id: 'dyForm',
                padding: '5 5 0 5',
                border: false,
                style: 'background-color: #fff;',

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'name',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'email',
                        fieldLabel: 'Email'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save'
            },
           {
                text: 'Add',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.onChange
            },
           ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    onChange : function(){alert('test');
         var form=Ext.getCmp("mainPanel");
        form.items.add(Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text", {fieldLabel:"First Name"}));
        form.doLayout(true);
   }
});
```

And I also want that on edit of this form I will load data to those new fields that i have newly created dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `onChange` function to

```
onChange : function(btn){
    // var form=Ext.getCmp("mainPanel");
    var form = btn.up('window').down('form'); // this is a better approach
    form.add(Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text", {fieldLabel:"First Name"}));
}
```

should do it. You added the field directly to the collection where you should have use the supplied `add` method of the form component.

see **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3fW3/4/)**

Comment: @anupkumar Yeah, there was a typo for the up navigation. see my edit and the working example

Comment: Can I do the same thing on change of combobox in extjs.

Comment: +1 for up and down methods. @sra *Congratz on your 10k this week :)*

Comment: @anupkumar Yes, use the select event for that.

Comment: Sorry,but i have used select event but does not get it.. How to create a form element there inside select like you have written for button " var form = btn.up('window').down('form');"

Comment: Thanks sra,it really helps me a lot. :)

Comment: @anupkumar You're welcome. In addition to accepting you could upvote my answer if it helped you that much ;)

Comment: @sra how can i create a dynamic field just below some specific textbox.Is there a way to do that because the dynamic fields that i am creating now come at the bottom of all fields.I need it at some specific place.